# Scipy distributions on symfit?

Tags: python, scipy, symfit

I think the title is self explaining.

I really want to use several pdfs already implemented on scipy.stats as models for a symfit model, e.g., [CrystalBall](http:///https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.crystalball.html) or [Johnson](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.johnsonsu.html) functions. I have tried with a gaussian distribution with the following code:

```
x = Variable('x') 
mu = Parameter('mu') 
sigma = Parameter('sigma') 
model_sci = stats.norm.pdf(y, mean, sigma)
```

But I get the following `TypeError`

> TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational

I believe it is because scipy distribution expects numbers (or iterables with numbers) instead of the symbol produced by sympy.
Is there a possible hack to uses this distributions and not implement them by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do this using a `CallableNumericalModel`:

```py
x = Variable('x') 
y = Variable('y') 
mu = Parameter('mu') 
sigma = Parameter('sigma') 

model_sci = lambda x, mu, sigma: stats.norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma)

model = CallableNumericalModel({y: model_sci}, connectivity_mapping={y: {x, mu, sigma}})
```

Comment: It worked like a charm! However, I really like to use SLSQP minimizer, but when I use it, the minimization does not return good fitted parameters.

For example, when I fit only with objective=Likelihood, I get mu=0.008 and sigma=1.00 (which is nice since the data comes from np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000)). 
But when I useobjective=Likelihood and minimizer=SLSQP, I got mu=-3.596625e+01 and sigma=-2.204207e+01.    Do you know why this happens? Cheers

Comment: So I tried to add limits on the Parameters and the fitted parameters are looking good, I will leave the last comment so if any one faces the same problem can look at my silly mistake and possibly correct their own